# HUE with Kerberized Hive

Tags: hive, hue

I'm attempting to connect HUE to my Kerberized Hive. After successfully obtaining and caching an initial ticket-granting ticket for the Hive principal using the command "kinit -kt  ," I can access and query the Hive databases and tables while starting HUE. I've created a HUE principal in Kerberos and granted it all necessary permissions to access Hive using apache ranger. However, when I use the HUE principal ticket and start HUE, I encounter an issue in the UI where I'm unable to access or query the Hive databases and tables. The error message I receive is as follows:

> Failed to validate proxy privilege of HUE for admin

[image: Error in HUE UI]

.

I have a couple of questions:

1.What's the process for configuring privileges for admin (HUE users)?

2.Is there an alternative method to connect to Hive without having to generate a ticket on the server? When I attempt to connect to Hive without initializing a ticket on the server, I encounter an error message saying, "No credentials available in the cache."

3.How to Kerberos between the users and Hue with the SPENGO backend ?